# Problem install OnionSwitch in kali?

Tags: tor, kali-linux

I am having an issue installing OnionSwitch for Tor on Kali.  I downloaded the zip from Git and and tried following the instructions listed at the Url.  https://github.com/Ned84/OnionSwitch

When I tried installing it using a package manager it said that it could not install because it is not a debian package.  So I tried to follow the instructions to build it and I just got the following error

```
 sudo pyinstaller --windowed --icon=Icon/onionswitch_icon.ico --clean --name 

OnionSwitch.app OnionSwitch_GUI.py
[sudo] password for adam: 
41 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5+498e6ee058
41 INFO: Python: 3.9.2
45 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.10.0-kali3-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
46 INFO: wrote /home/adam/Downloads/Debian_OnionSwitch_V1.3/OnionSwitch_V1.3/OnionSwitch.app.spec
54 INFO: UPX is available.
55 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in /root/.cache/pyinstaller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.5+498e6ee058', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/adam/Downloads/Debian_OnionSwitch_V1.3/OnionSwitch_V1.3/OnionSwitch.app.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['OnionSwitch_GUI.py'],
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 190, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script '/home/adam/Downloads/Debian_OnionSwitch_V1.3/OnionSwitch_V1.3/OnionSwitch_GUI.py' not found
```

Comment: This is not a security question or even about tor or onion routing. This is a simple installation problem in a linux distro.

Comment: Have you read the error message? (If not, why not?): PyInstaller obviously could not find the `OnionSwitch_GUI.py` script where it expects it. Did you check for its presence at the location PyInstaller points you to?